# Passing value of a variable/ object through http request

Tags: android

I am opening a webpage by calling 
jobAccept.jsp?contents=result.text&format=result.
but the value of result.text is dynamic. how to pass the value of result.text instead itself?

Comment: maybe building this url like this? `"jobAccept.jsp?contents=" + result.text + "&format=result"`

Comment: I was using this in window.open(). you think i can still do this.? I was calling a webpage and passing these values there to use the values to fill boxes dynamically

Answer (score 1):

Use some sting formatting like this:

```
String url = String.format("jobAccept.jsp?contents=%s&format=result", result.text);
```

Comment: I tried but no luck. I was trying to pass two values as of now both result.text and result are dynamic.

Comment: That is still a pretty simple fix just do this 
`String url = String.format("jobAccept.jsp?contents=%s&format=%s", result.text, result.toString());`
You can only use this string formatting technique with a primitive (or a string) though, so if result is a model with multiple associated primitives (which it probably is since it has a property called text) you cannot pass it in as a GET param.

Comment: http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/lang/string/java-string-format-example/ worth a read.